# How could I attach tags to my Cloudwatch agent log output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

How could I attach instance tags like this into my cloudwatch agent log files?:

[image]

My current config looks like this:

```
{
    "metrics": {
        "namespace": "Testing2",
        "aggregation_dimensions": [
            [
                "InstanceId"
            ]
        ],
        "append_dimensions": {
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
        },

        "metrics_collected": {
            "Processor Information": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Processor Utility"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            
            "Memory": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Committed Bytes In Use",
                    "Available Bytes"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            
            "Network Interface": {
                "measurement": [
                    "Bytes Received/sec",
                    "Bytes Sent/sec"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },

            "LogicalDisk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "% Free Space",
                    "Free Megabytes",
                    "Disk Read Bytes/sec",
                    "Disk Write Bytes/sec"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output I am getting looks like this:

```
{"metric_stream_name":"QuickPartial-607uQD","account_id":"***","region":"us-east-1","namespace":"Testing2","metric_name":"LogicalDisk Free Megabytes","dimensions":{"InstanceId":"i-***","instance":"D:","objectname":"LogicalDisk"},"timestamp":1657211580000,"value":{"max":10196.0,"min":10196.0,"sum":10196.0,"count":1.0},"unit":"None"}
```

I would like to have it so that it could be:

```
 {"metric_stream_name":"QuickPartial-607uQD","account_id":"***", "Name":"Cloudwatch-testing"...
```

I am new to AWS and I am struggling to understand concepts like dimensions and stuff, so please try to explain it simply.

Any suggestions is appreciated!